# what does `curl -e` or `curl --referer` mean?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I've seen some example :-

`curl --referer http://example.com/bot.html http://www.cyberciti.biz/`

what is the different if I use `curl http://www.cyberciti.biz/`

shell script type:-

```
curl -e http://example.com/bot.html \ 
'http://www.cyberciti.biz/'
```

what is `\` for?

Comment: Did you check `man curl`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the backslash is to escape the line break. Unless someone else can tell me otherwise.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the `man` [page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) of `cURL`

```
-e, --referer <URL>
```

> (HTTP) Sends the "Referrer Page" information to the HTTP server. This
>   can also be set with the -H, --header flag of course. When used with
>   -L, --location you can append ";auto" to the --referer URL to make curl automatically set the previous URL when it follows a Location:
>   header. The ";auto" string can be used alone, even if you don't set an
>   initial --referer.

Essentially this tells the server which page sent you there.